How can I dynamically export classes in raku?
I am updating a raku module (Physics::Measure)
My old code looks like this:
unit module Physics::Measure ...

class Length             is Measure is export {}
class Mass               is Measure is export {}
class Current            is Measure is export {}
...

On the client side, we go:
use Physics::Measure;

say my Length $b = 15m;    #15m

To handle localisation, I would like to declare and export these classes programatically, something like:
my @names = <Length Mass Current>;

for @names -> $name {
    class ::($name) is Measure is export {}
}

This gives the error Name ::($name) is not compile-time known, and can not serve as a package name.
Okaay, so maybe (from the docs) I can go something like:
my package EXPORT::DEFAULT {
    for @names -> $name {
        OUR::($name) := $name;
    }
}

-or maybe, with a for loop tbd-
sub EXPORT {
    Map.new:
        ($name => Length is Measure)
}

Please can someone provide a steer on the best way to (i) dynamically declare the classes and (ii) then to export them???

The secret is really in the notion the names of the classes shouldn't be dynamic, but the names with which they are exported should be dynamic:
# file lib/Physics/Measure.rakumod
class Length  {}
class Mass    {}
class Current {}

sub EXPORT(*@names) {
    Map.new( @names.map: -> $from, $to { $to => ::($from) } )
}

This would allow you to specify orginal name -> wanted name pairs as such:
$ raku -Ilib -e 'use Physics::Measure <Length Foo Current Bar>; dd Foo, Bar'
Length
Current

This is the basic mechanism for handling any non-named arguments in a use statement.  Using named arguments is currently handled by the default handler, and that sadly currently not possible.  A much more natural interface would have been :Length<Foo>, :Current<Bar>.

Thanks for your quick answer --- this is half the story so far so good, but I want to be able to pick up different class names like <Longueur Masse Temps> from a localization file ... so can I declare class names dynamically too?

But that's just my point: you can't without getting into QAST / RakuAST land.  But you can rename them when they're being imported into a scope.

Ah - OK. Well there is a strong need for Macros in this module (the code could be a lot simpler / faster if the 227 unit objects could be instantiated and held in the precomp)  ... but I am leaving that for the next big upgrade in the hope that macros come along ;-) ... meantime, I think I will hardwire the classnames into each local variant of the Measure module (ie use the package manager so that the common code is provided by a "parent" module and then each child is the localized version ... appreciate the guidance!

I don't think that macros would solve your problem either, as these also run at compile time.  Could you please gist a sample of what you're planning to do?  So we can see whether we understand each other?

sorry the macro stuff was an aside --- I haven't really thought that through enough to ask a cogent question
